# GAM model with hours s factors

Tags: r, model, regression, gam

Im trying to set a gam model. My data set contains of hours that are set as factors. When I try setting I always get an error and dont know why. So I want to smooth hour 0 and hour 12 in the model. I hope that someone of you can help me.

Here are the codes to understand how my data set is built:

```
data$time = substr(data$x, 1, 16)
data$start_time <- as.POSIXct(data$start_time, format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M", tz = "UTC")
data = subset(data, select = -c(x, y))
data$hour <- hour(data$start_time)
head(data)

df = data %>%
  mutate(data_aggregate = floor_date(time, unit = "hour")) %>%
  group_by(data_aggregate) %>%
  summarise(W = sum(WindInfeed, na.rm = TRUE))

df1 <-  df %>% mutate(hour = as.factor(hour(data_aggregate)))

The hours I defined for my linear regression model in a dummy matrix:
df1$hour <- as.factor(df1$hour)
dummy_matrix <- model.matrix(~hour-1, data = df1)
df_new <- cbind(dummy_matrix, df1)

gam.lm2 <- gam(W~s(hour0) + s(hour12), data = df_new) 

> dput(head(df1[c(1, 3)]))
structure(list(data_aggregate = structure(c(1640995200, 1640998800, 
1641002400, 1641006000, 1641009600, 1641013200), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), hour = structure(1:6, levels = c("0", "1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
"16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

and this are the information of the new data set including the dummy matrix 

> dput(head(df_new[c(1, 3)]))
structure(list(hour0 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), hour2 = c(0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you share a reproducible exameple, e.g. edit your question to include a sample of data using `dput()`? It makes it easier for others to help. Can you also share the error you are getting? Your `gam` model here uses `hour12` and `df_new` and it isn't clear where these have been defined.

Comment: The error that occurs is: Error in smooth.construct.tp.smooth.spec(object, dk$data, dk$knots) :

Comment: You’re missing the rest of the error. Please edit your question to add the requested information

Comment: Anyway, you can’t smooth factors and you can smooth a variable that takes only two values. It makes no sense to me what you are doing.